# Creating a sub directory in FTP and uploading file

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I have created a FTP directory and upload file that directory. It is working 99% time. But sometime it does not create directory and interesting this is, it uploads file to root folder. Why?

```
public bool UploadCommandToFtp(ExtraStoreTransaction exstores)
    {
        try
        {
            FTPclient ftp = new FTPclient(_ftpHostName, _ftpUserName, _ftpPassword);
            ftp.FtpCreateDirectory("/"+"Commands/" + exstores.Id);
            ftp.CurrentDirectory = "/"+"Commands/" + exstores.Id;
            string[] fileName = Directory.GetFiles(_workerPath + exstores.Id + "\\");
            string filename = Path.GetFileName(fileName[0]);

            if (ftp.FtpFileExists(filename))
            {
                if (!ftp.FtpDelete(Path.GetFileName(fileName[0])))
                    return false;
            }

            if (ftp.Upload(_workerPath + exstores.Id + "\\" + filename, filename))
                return true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return false;

        }
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: What are the possible values of exstores.Id?

Comment: any integer value that is unique

Comment: Could it ever be negative or are there duplicates?